# Discord.py - Server mute user

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using discord.py but not using command and I have no intention in changing. To explain the goal of the bot I will use a small scheme:

1. server member sends a message like this: £Start @user#0001
2. pinged user gets server muted (no one can hear him in any voice chat)
3. 10 seconds pass
4. user gets unmuted
5. 1-minute passes
6. user gets muted and so on forever...

I know this is a Troll bot. But we need to have fun sometime...

I have already done the biggest part, but I'm having trouble muting the user.

```py
# IMPORT
import discord
import time

# VARIABLES
token = "sorry but no"
client = discord.Client()

# CODE
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    start = False

    # CODE
    if message.content.startswith("£Start <@!"):
        # Extract id from message
        message_content = message.content
        user_id = message_content.replace("£Start <@!", "")
        user_id = user_id.replace(">", "")

        rep_message = message
        await message.delete()
        start = True
        user_obj = await rep_message.guild.fetch_member(user_id)

        if str(user_obj.status) != "online" and start is True:  # if user is online and start is True:
            # loop
            while start:
                # NEED HELP HERE >> server mute = True
                time.sleep(10)
                # NEED HELP HERE >> server mute = False
                time.sleep(30)
        else:
            return
    else:
        return

client.run(token)
```

I hope is clear enough where I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) passing `mute=True`.

```
await user_obj.edit(mute=True)
```

You should also be using `await asyncio.sleep` to sleep, to avoid blocking the event loop