# How to do mute command in on_message()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I don't now how to do mute in on_message() here's what I tried

```
if message.content.startswith(f"_mute {member.id}")
  And there was mute code( I think this part should be working)
```

I don't now why this won't work

Comment: The only way I can think of is to create a role that disables voice chat, then give the member that role.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806930/1935238) help?

Comment: Is `member` already defined?  Please show us a [mcve]  (your entire `on_message` event)